# IntelliJ - does a new version overwrite

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

Simple question hopefully.

I have a Mac and want to install IntelliJ 13.1.

If I download the latest version will it overwrite my current version and keep my settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not override your current version. It automatically detects that there is an existing version of IntelliJ and asks whether you want to import settings.

Source : I once had a mac with 2 versions of IntelliJ(version 11 and 12) idea running on the same machine.

Comment: Thanks - is there anyway to force it overwrite and keep the settings - is that an option?

Comment: Manually you can do it.You can install the newer version importing the configurations and then delete the older version.I am not aware whether you get that option while installing the new version.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what version you have and what the new version is. Major versions will *not* overwrite because the application names are different. Minor versions *will* overwrite, because they have the same application name.

For example,

```
Intellij IDEA 12 -> Intellij IDEA 13 = Intellij IDEA 12 and Intellij IDEA 13 apps
Intellij IDEA 13 -> Intellij IDEA 13.1 = Intellij IDEA 13 application
```

In all cases, the settings and preferences are stored outside the application, and will not be overwritten with the new application. For major version upgrades, you will likely be asked if you want to keep your settings, or wipe them and start fresh. For minor version upgrades, your settings will simply be used as-is.